# Asciidoctor: how to layout two code blocks side by side?

Tags: asciidoctor

Is it possible to have two code blocks side-by-side using Asciidoctor? I could  not find any examples in the [documentation](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoctor/latest/) or on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

```
= Side by side

Enjoy these code samples:

[cols="a,a", options="header"]
|===
| JavaScript
| Perl

|
[source, javascript]
----
console.log('Hello World!')
----

|
[source, perl]
----
#!/usr/bin/env perl

print "Hello World!\n"
----
|===
```

Produces:

[image]